# PowerShell worklfow issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm unable to access workflow variables in child-scope even when I'm qualifying it with $workflow prefix:

```
workflow Test-3 {
      $services = "w32time", "spooler"
      $name = "Workflow Test"
      write-verbose -Message ("Local count is {0}" -f $services.Count)
     parallel {
       write-verbose -Message "Name in parallel clause is $workflow:name"
       sequence {
         $seqServices = Get-Service -Name $workflow:services
         write-verbose -Message ("Seq count is {0}" -f $seqServices.Count)
       }
     }
```

}

And this is what I see in the output:

VERBOSE:[localhost]:Local count is 2

VERBOSE:[localhost]:Name in parallel clause is

VERBOSE:[localhost]:Seq count is 165

Appreciate if someone could point out the deviations in the output.

thanks
SJ

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I cannot pass collections within a sequence block. I got it to work by creating a local collection. Enumerating the parent collection ($workflow:var) works..

```
sequence {
$seqServices = @()
foreach($s in $workflow:services){$seqServices += $s}
#This works now
$psServices = Get-Service -Name $seqServices
write-Verbose -Message ("Sequence count is {0}" -f $psServices.Count)
```

}

I see this now..

VERBOSE:[localhost]:Sequence count is 2